# Variable printing but not being written into file scrapy

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a scrapy crawler that can go on links and find other links and when I run it again it finds links on those sites.
[Here's my current code](https://hastebin.com/atinaviduc.py).

At the bottom of the code you'll see it says

```
        print(parents)
        print(fust)
        thefile.write(parents)
        thefile.write("~")
        thefile.write(str(response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()[counta]))
        thefile.write("\n")
```

When I run the crawler for the second time after collecting links then it prints the parents variable, as an example:

> http://roblox.com~http://en.help.roblox.com/

... but when I run it for the second time it scrapes `http://en.help.roblox.com/`, prints

> http://roblox.com~http://en.help.roblox.com/

... as the parents var just before `thefile.write(parents)`, but when it does `thefile.write(parents)` it seems to write

> ~https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004630823-Roblox-Privacy-and-Cookie-Policy

... and doesn't write the parents var into it.  How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: please fix the formatting of your question ...

Comment: how do I go around doing that? What exactly is un formatted?

Comment: when you edit you get explanation on how to edit... 4 spaces is code block etc